# Random Color for <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, css

So overall I am trying to make the boxes change color when someone puts a mouse over them. Color has to be random. I know I am missing a connection point between my functions but I cant figure out what it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmousedown='event.preventDefault();'
      onmouseenter = "colorize();"
>
<head>
<title> Boxes </title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>

  table {
    border-spacing: 6px;
    border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
    margin-top: .5in;
    margin-left: 1in;
}
   td {
    width: 40px; height: 40px; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<script>
```

Create a function called colorize that is passed an element object as its
parameter and sets the elements background color style property using the
rgb(r,g,b) method setting each r,g and b to a random number between 0 and
255.

```
  function colorize() {

   var
    r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
   return '#' +r+g+b;
  }

  function colorize(co) {
   document.body.style.background = co;
  }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <script type="text/javascript">
```

Use document.write() and for-loops to fill in the table to create a 16x16    box table. For each td element, create a onmouseenter call to colorize, passing it the element itself (this).

```
  var row = 16;
  var cols = 16;

  for(var r=0;r<row;r++){
   document.write("</tr>");

  for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
   document.write("<td></td>"); 
  }

   document.write("</tr>");
  }
  </script>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting so your code is legible.

Comment: Hope that helps you!

Comment: what if your text font color is same as the background color?

Comment: @LarryG Your second definition of `colorize` overwrites the first. And you're never calling either.

Comment: @TeaCode I don't need any text for this. So there would be no reason to change text font color. I'm only trying to color the background of the boxes. Essentially i want to fill them when they get mouseover.

Comment: @Carcigenicate i'm not 100% on the how to call to the boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with body background, nothing said about that in your text. ALos your colorizer func is overwritten. maybe you wanted something like this... ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Boxes </title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>
table {
  border-spacing: 6px;
  border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
  margin-top: .5in;
  margin-left: 1in;
}
td {
  width: 40px; height: 40px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
  
<script>
   function colorize(el) {
     var r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
       el.style.backgroundColor = '#' +r+g+b;
  }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var row = 16;
    var cols = 16;

  for(var r=0;r<row;r++){
    document.write("</tr>");

    for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
      document.write("<td onMouseEnter='colorize(this);'></td>"); 
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
  </script>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm glad it is what you wanted, but please note that this is far from optimal code. There are several optimizations to be done here and I wouldn't use this as is unless it's some hobby project.

Comment: It looks like i went wrong not establishing and ID for the colorize where you put the "el".

Comment: It was more than that. It was onMouseOut and other events on document.body which I removed. it was duplicate colorize function which was overwriting one another. At last your colorize function just returned colorcode (to nothing) instead asigning it to passed TD element.

Comment: I seen that. I meant to comment one out before posting but I couldn't decide which one was closer to being correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your colorize function update each cell in your table. Replace both **colorize()** and **colorize(co)** with one function:

```
function colorize() {
     var r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
        b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);

     for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("td").length; i++){
        document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].style.backgroundColor = "#"+r+g+b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i play with Ids and adding onmousedown in html tag that calls the func.

```js
function colorize() {

   var
    r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
   return '#' +r+g+b;
  }


function change(){ 
   var x = document.getElementById("1");
    var y = document.getElementById("2");
    x.style.color = colorize();
    y.style.color = colorize();

 }
```

```html
 <table frame="box" onmousedown="change()"id="1" >
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table> 

 <table frame="box" onmousedown="change()" id="2" >
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```